# Android app crashing without crash showing in Firebase

Tags: android, crash, firebase-crash-reporting, azure-mobile-engagement

Customers are reporting that our app is suddenly crashing and restarting to the same activity.

We are mainly using Azure Mobile Engagement and some crashes show there. These crashes have all been tracked down to code bugs.

Since the customer still reported crashes that we didn't see in Azure Mobile Engagement we added Firebase Crash Reporting and the customer reported that there are even more crashes now and nothing is showing in Firebase nor Azure Mobile Engagement.

Under which circumstances can an app crash/unload without it being reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Crash Reporting currently can't capture native exceptions (C/C++ code).  Other crash reporters that are not well-behaved may also prevent it from working correctly.

Any Java code that throws an uncaught exception that would cause the dialog box with the text "Unfortunately, XYZapp has stopped" should show up in the console, given that the app can remain running at some point long enough for the data to be transmitted.

Comment: Could you comment on what native exceptions are? We haven't done any native code in our application and I'll have to verify with out customers, but I would bet that the app sometimes crashes without the "Unfortunately, xxx has stopped". Is there any way I can see how often these crashes happen and possibly what was happening (i.e. which activity was running) when the crash occured.

Comment: Native exceptions are just those that happen anywhere outside Java application code.  They could coming from Android itself, or a misuse of Java APIs.  Firebase is planning on adding support for native exceptions some time in the future.

Comment: What are all possible situations when crash is no sent by design? Is there some restriction for emulators or debug builds?

Comment: @TomášHubálek The client will always try to send any crash that it captures, but there may be situations where the server rejects it (for example, clients that are exceeding reasonable limits).  Also, if a crash can not be sent for some amount of time (no network connectivity), or there are too many crashes queued up, it may drop some crashes to prevent excessive storage.